# Outlook Addin Settings and Auto-Implemented Properties

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have an outlook addin that sets some values in the addin options page.  There are then properties that are initialized to the values of the settings like so:

`public string Prop1 { get; } = Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1;`

My question is if the value of `Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1` is changed during runtime through the addin options page, will the property reflect the change?

From what I understand it generates a hidden backing field to hold the value of the property which I am initializing it to.

So the property is not equivalent to

```
public string Prop1 
{
    get {
        return Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1;
    }
}
```

but is

```
public string Prop1 
{
    get {
        return hidden_backing_field;
    }
}
```

Which would mean that `Prop1` wouldn't reflect the changed value of `Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1`.

How would I handle such a case?  Would I need to make sure to re-set the property each time the options are changed?

Thanks in advance for helping clear up my confusion with auto-implemented properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the property would be initialized only once when the object is created. Why not simply always return the desired value?

```
public string Prop1 
{
    get {
        return Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the best way.  I suppose auto-implemented properties are not the correct thing to use here.